# How to set up nginx as reverse proxy to wordpress site hosted on apache2 with pretty permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, apache2, reverse-proxy, permalinks

With the following settings I am able to access the wordpress site which is hosted at localhost:8080 but the problem occurs when I enable the wordpress URL structure as post name instead of regular query string from permalinks settings.

```
   #nginx server settings
   server {
           listen 80;
           listen [::]:80;
           server_name blog.mysite.com;

           #use https always
           return 307 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            listen [::]:443 ssl;

            error_log             /etc/nginx/logs/blog.mysite.com.log;

            ssl                  on;
            ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mysite.com/cert.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mysite.com/privkey.pem;
            proxy_set_header     X-SSL-CLIENT-CERT $ssl_client_cert;

            server_name             blog.mysite.com;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }
    }
```

also I have added the following snippet to wp-config.php

```
   //wp-config.php modifications

   if($_SERVER['HTTP_X-FORARDED-FOR'] == 'https') {
       $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'
   }

   if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORARDED_HOST']) {
       $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORARDED_HOST']
   }
```

I just want to use nginx as reverse proxy as I am planning to host nodejs apps on the same server, also I never used php fast cgi with nginx so any solution with my existing environment is preferable.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you created an `.htaccess` file [as described here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29)?